# MqttAndroidClient not able to connect to mosquitto

Tags: java, android, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have a mosquitto broker running on my computer with `mosquitto -v` and I'm trying to connect to it from my android app. What I am doing is

```
public void connect() {
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(context, "mqtt://192.168.1.198:1883", clientId);
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(callback);

        mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);

        mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, context, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);
                    mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Connected to the broker");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Not able to connect to the broker");
                }
        });

        while(!mqttAndroidClient.isConnected()) {}
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("notify/new", 0);
        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            System.err.println("Exception whilst subscribing");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But it never connects, because I don't see the "Connected to the broker" message and it gets in stuck in the while loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Move the subscribe code into the `onSuccess()` callback. That tight while loop will just max out the CPU

Comment: Alright that works, but what if I want to subscribe to another topic in a second moment?

Answer (score 1):

As covered in the comments, the tight while loop checking if the client is connected is redundant as there is already a callback `onSuccess()` that can be used for that test.

The call to `subscribe()` should be moved into the callback.

The best way to handle subscribing to topics after the client is connected is to gate the call to `subscribe()` in an if block that checks the connected status. If that test fails add the topic to a global array, and call `connect()` again. The `subscribe()` in the `onSuccess()` callback should use the version that takes an array of topics